# how can I find/match names to object collection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery collection $("#Users") which contains a string with names:

```
'Bob Beffer, Eddie Queen'
```

I would like to match this to another (gridrow)collection:

```
string[] rowObject
```

say `rowObject[1]` contains names how can I match/find the names in the rowObject array when i loop though the array? I tried:

```
if ($("#Users").val().find(rowObject[1]) != null) {
```

..etc

Comment: Well, first thing I notice is that you're running jQuery's find() method on a string, which won't work. But your question is hard to understand, so I imagine that that's just scratching the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var rowObject = [ "Bob Beffer", "Another name", "And another" ];
var names = $("#Users").val().split(", "); // Bob Beffer, Eddie Queen
var filteredNames = $.grep(names, function (name) {
  return ~rowObject.indexOf(name); 
});
```

`filteredNames` will then just contain `Bob Beffer` since `Eddie Queen` does not exist in `rowObject`.